Taking the derivative of a generic function... Not sure how to get a factor of 2
I'm working on a problem involving a function and its nested dependency. The problem statement provides a PDE and its derivatives, and I'm trying to understand how the second derivative term is derived, particularly how the coefficient '2' appears.
The provided PDE is:
$ f(m_t,\sigma) = g(m_t, I(m_t,t)) $
where $ I(m_t, t) $ is a nested function. The first and second derivatives with respect to $ m $ are given by:

First derivative:
$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial m} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} $

Second derivative:
$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m \partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2} $


Given these derivatives, the solution provided in the document for the second derivative includes a coefficient '2' in the mixed partial derivative term:
$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m \partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2} $
Here's my understanding and work on the derivation:
Starting with the function $ f(m_t, \sigma) = g(m_t, I(m_t, t)) $:

The first derivative of $ f $ with respect to $ m $:

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial m} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} $

The second derivative of $ f $ with respect to $ m $:

$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial m} \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} \right) $
Distributing:
$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial m} \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} \right) $
Applying the product rule, we get:
$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m \partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2} $
However, in the document, the provided solution includes a '2' before the mixed partial derivative term:
$
 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m \partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2}
$
I'm unclear on how this '2' appears. Can someone explain how the factor of '2' comes into play in the second derivative of the function $ f(m_t, \sigma) $? If the '2' isn't supposed to be there, is there a simple way to modify the $g(\cdot)$ so that it is present?

Let us start with the first term on the RHS, $\frac {\partial g}{\partial m}$. Differentiating with respect to $m$ and using the chain rule yields:
$$\frac {\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + \frac {\partial^2 g}{\partial m \, \partial I} \frac {\partial I}{\partial m}$$
Next we differentiate the second term $\frac {\partial g}{\partial I} \frac {\partial I}{\partial m}$ with respect to $m$. As before we use the chain rule but now also the product rule:
$$\frac {\partial^2 g}{\partial I \, \partial m} \frac {\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac {\partial^2 g}{\partial I^2} \left(\frac {\partial I}{\partial m}\right)^2 + \frac {\partial g}{\partial m} \frac {\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2} $$
Adding the two results gives us the answer:
$$\frac {\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac {\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + 2\frac {\partial^2 g}{\partial m \, \partial I} \frac {\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac {\partial^2 g}{\partial I^2} \left(\frac {\partial I}{\partial m}\right)^2 + \frac {\partial g}{\partial m} \frac {\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2} $$
This explains the appearance of the factor $2$ that the OP did not understand. Note that the third term that I obtained in my derivation is missing in the official answer.

Could you elaborate more on how to differentiate the second term? For example how come my attempt with the product rule is incorrect? Also could you explain how the chain rule yields your result? Apologees for being slow to understand

Sure ! The second term is a product. Hence we need the product rule of differentiation. But the term with $g$ depends both on $m$ directly, and through $I(m)$ indirectly. So we also need the chain rule. This means we get three terms. (a) Differentiating $g$ with respect to $m$. (b) Differentiating $g$ with respect to $I$, and $I$ with respect to $m$. (c) Differentiating $I$ with respect to $m$. I hope this helps.

Thank you! So the partial of g wrt I still depends on m when we're doing the product rule step?

Yes. The derivative of $g$ with respect to $I$ will in general depend on $m$, in an indirect way as a function of $I$. This chain rule effect must be taken into account when (or before) you apply the product rule.

I posted a follow on trying to make sure I understand the steps. Your feedback would be awesome but thank you for your help on this post!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4941840/help-with-multivariate-function-derivative-algebra-middle-terms-dont-match-a

@financial_physician I have a question for you. How is it possible that the official answer, which as you say is in a document, is wrong? Who is the author of the document? Is he a mathematician? That would be hard to believe.

He's not a mathematician, he's someone I'm doing research with who's a professor at a university I'm currently located close to (my day job is boring so this is for fun / I'm thinking of going back to school to do something more interesting with my life haha). I want to make sure I understand what we're doing so I'm trying to re-derive what we're doing step by step

Also probably important to note that he's just sending me some research notes. I'm sure everything will get more formal once he's ready to share it. He just wrote a doc to give me context on some of the stuff we're doing. It's not published
