Help with multivariate function derivative algebra... Middle terms don't match as expected
Intro
I want to compute $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2}$
where we define $ f(m,\sigma) = g(m, I(m, t)) $
I asked about this in a prior question, however I'm realizing that I don't actually understand the answer as well as I'd like to.
I'd like to provide my work as thoroughly as possible so hopefully my mistake can be pointed out / I can understand the correct computational process.
Goal
I want to compute $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2}$
where we define $ f(m,\sigma) = g(m, I(m, t)) $
I should find that:
$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m \partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2}
$
My Work
Taking the first derivative is no problem.
$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial m} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m}
$
Now taking the second derivative
$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right) \\
&=\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial m \partial I}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} +\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right)}
\end{align}
$
I believe it's the braced term in the brace that has me confused. My thought is that we have we have two functions being multiplied together implying that we need to use the product rule. Thus, the braced term:
$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right) = \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial I}\right)}_{A} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right)}_{B}
\end{align}
$
In the equation above, I've placed braces for the terms we need to take the derivatives of:
For this first derivative, $A$, I think we still have to account for the $m$ that directly influence $g$ so this term will become two (similar to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial m}$). -- (This part actually confuses me because I thought we were already holding the outer $m$ constant.) --
$
\begin{align}
A = \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial I}\right)  =  \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial I \partial m}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial I^2}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}
\end{align}
$
And then for the second brace, $B$, I think this one is just straightforward
$
\begin{align}
B = \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 I }{\partial m^2}
\end{align}
$
Now substituting our solutions back into equation (3).
$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right) = \left(\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial I \partial m}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial I^2}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right) \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I}\frac{\partial^2 I }{\partial m^2}
\end{align}
$
Then we substitute this solution back for our original underbrace.
$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial m \partial I}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \left(\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial I \partial m}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial I^2}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right) \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I}\frac{\partial^2 I }{\partial m^2}
\end{align}
$
My middle term doesn't look like the one I was hoping to recover. (The first and third match which seems good.)
$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + 2 \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m \partial I} \frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial I} \frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2}
$
Could I get some help understanding where my error(s) are? I might need a relatively thorough explanation since I'm not the strongest mathematician.

Everything you did in the braces was correct. What you did wrong was in the very beginning before all the brace work, because $$\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial m}\right)\neq \frac{\partial^2g}{\partial m^2}$$

Why is there no $\partial^2 g/\partial I^2$ term? Also, $\sigma$ should be $t$?

@NinadMunshi right, is it:
$ \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial m}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial m^2} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial m \partial I}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} $
?

@TedShifrin where should that term be? I guess I have that term as part of my middle term (it's in the second part of the the middle term)
For your other question, $\sigma = I(\cdot)$

No, $f$ is a function of $m$ and $t$. I strongly recommend thinking of $g$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ and writing the partial derivatives of $g$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, ultimately evaluated at $(m,I(m,t))$. Both $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(m,I(m,t))$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(m,I(m,t))$ need to be differentiated with respect to $m$. You will have a $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}(\frac{\partial I}{\partial m})^2$ term.

@TedShifrin are you saying to set $x = m$ and $y = I(x,t) = \sigma$?

@TedShifren so far the correction that I understand is that [NinadMunshi] pointed out I missed a term when computing $\partial / \partial m (\partial g / \partial m)$. Where should I have noticed the missing terms you're mentioning?
To be honest, I'm punching above my weight with this question so it's very possible I'm missing obvious concepts that it seems like I should know

I'll try to write it out a bit more carefully for you. Your revised effort is close, but I insist (after 40+ years of teaching multivariable calculus) on keeping abuse of notation to a minimum. We start with the function $g(x,y)$ (as differentiable as we need) and define $f(m,t)=g(m,I(m,t))$. You want $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2}$. We apply the chain rule twice, proceeding with care.
First,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial m} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(m,I(m,t)) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(m,I(m,t))\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}. \tag{$\star$}$$
Then we differentiate again with respect to $m$. We will need to apply the chain rule to each term on the right-hand side. Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(m,I(m,t)) &= \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(m,I(m,t)) + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y\partial x}(m,I(m,t))\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}, \quad\text{and} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(m,I(m,t)) &= \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y}(m,I(m,t)) + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}(m,I(m,t))\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}.
\end{align*}
Of course, we need to use the product rule as well when we differentiate the second term of ($\star$). (I will now drop the $(m,I(m,t))$ for ease of reading, but remember to evaluate all the terms appropriately.) The final result, then, will be
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial m^2} &= \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \left(\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right)\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2} \\
&= \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}+ 2\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial I}{\partial m} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}\left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial m}\right)^2 + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 I}{\partial m^2}.
\end{align*}

Thank you! I'm very close to your answer. I have an extra del I / del m next to my del^2 g/(del x del y) term. Once I noodle out why that's different I think I'll be good

I think you should follow my approach carefully, as it helps keep the bookkeeping as painless as possible. ;) Your first term in A is wrong .

Yeah you're saying I shouldn't have the second part of my first term in A... I thought I needed it by the chain rule on del g/ del I?

In my notation, you’re differentiating $\partial g/\partial y(m,I(m,t))$ with respect to $x$. Thus, no further chain rule. Truly, using $m$ abuses notation and totally leads to your confusion. Please consider changing stubborn bad habits.

Ah I see what you're saying now. I'm going to mark this as accepted. Now that I get what's actually happening, I'll do it your way. Thank you for walking me through this! Kind of you to still help even in retirement

It was a pleasure, and I hope it’ll help you do such things in the future!

@financial_physician In my opinion you should get yourself a highschool mathematics book. It will explain the chain rule and the product rule of differentiation. It will also have many examples, so that you can improve your skills. Furthermore, tell your professor that the expression he derived is wrong !

@M.Wind any suggestions? (For text)
